# understanding express code flow

Tags: express

I am learning and trying to understand expressjs deeply.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', ...);
```

Could you please inform me where the `app.get` method is defined in the [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) module? 
I want to learn the code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods including `app.get()` are [defined here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e5ec966b2f068e935ea1b33374fac133dd06cdc8/lib/application.js#L468) followed by `app.all()`.

Comment: could you please help me where the 'mixin(app, proto, false);' method defines in express.js line 42

Comment: founded 'merge-descriptors' module index.js the 'merge' method.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, is your issue resolved?